# Adding css style into javascript

Tags: javascript, css

What's the proper syntax to add css into the below script in the if condition?

```
function validateEmail(emailField){
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

        if (reg.test(emailField.value) == false) 
        {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');
            return false;
        }

        return true;
```

Comment: what do you mean *add css*. Do you mean change the styling of an HTML element?

Comment: @AmmarCSE yes based on the if condition

Comment: I think you meant regex, not CSS style. css style is something like font-size, background-color, etc. You just want to validate email address with javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh no i meant css.. trying to add a color effect to the input field based on the outcome of the if condition

Comment: Why didn't you specify your question like your comment?

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh sorry but didn't want to know a specific thing..Just wanted to know the general concept, for future use.

Comment: This may help you find what you're looking for:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: @AntonioDangond thank you!

Comment: [HTML5 Form Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)

Answer (score 2):

Create a span with an id

```
<span id="emailMsg">Wrong Email format</span>
```

and you can do this in your script

```
function validateEmail(emailField){
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

    if (reg.test(emailField.value) == false) 
    {
        document.getElementById('emailMsg').style.color = '#FF0000';
        return false;
    }

    return true;
```

Note that I didn't validate your regex. I simply added javascript that changes color.

Answer (score -1):

Using JQuery, you can easily modify any element using [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/), in this case by 
specifying

```
$(emailField).css('color', '#F00');
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery tag?